# How to Fix HTTP Request Smuggling on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, iis, http-headers

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I want to resolve the [HTTP Request Smuggling Vulnerability](https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling) issue.

I thought it would be sufficient if I blocked the requests which have a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header. In the IIS administration menu, I added a new Request Filtering rule for this. However that does not seem to fix it.

I wrote little .NET code to test if IIS generates a 404 error when chunked content is sent. When I add the transfer encoding header 1 time to my test client code as below, I do NOT receive 404—I receive 200.

```cs
httpRequest.Headers.Add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
```

Interestingly, if I add the header 2 times (I mean duplicate it) like

```cs
httpRequest.Headers.Add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
httpRequest.Headers.Add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
```

The filtering rule applies, and I receive 404 as I expected.

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 2):

A few months later, Microsoft added a patch wherein you can [disable request smuggling with a registry key](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/ADV200008).

> 1. Click Start, click Run, type `Regedit` in the Open box, and then click OK.
> 2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`
> 3. Set `DWORD` type value `DisableRequestSmuggling` to one of the following:
>
>    - Set to 0 to disable the filter
>    - Set to 1 to enable the filter
> 4. Exit Registry Editor.
> 5. Restart the computer.